# Python3 and permutations / combinations

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, permutation

I am trying to solve one small conversion problem in Python3. Have input file with "blocks" of data and need to create output file with all non-repeating combinations of it. My math knowledge is too limited for it, maybe when I explain it, someone can give me advise.

Input file contains block separated by line with semicolon on start followed by ID-string, followed by pairs of values (each on new line) corresponding to status string. Output file should contain lines in fixed format where the line starts always with ID-string and then 2 pairs of coordinates. For each ID-string from input, should output contain all possible non-repeating combinations of the pairs from input (corresponding to ID block).

```
Example:
input file
;
ID1
X1
Y1
X2
Y2
X3
Y3
;
ID2
X1
Y1
X2
Y2

output file
ID1;X1;Y1;X2;Y2
ID1;X1;Y1;X3;Y3
ID1;X2;Y2;X1;Y1
ID1;X2;Y2;X3;Y3
ID1;X3;Y3;X1;Y1
ID1;X3;Y3;X2;Y2
ID2;X1;Y1;X2;Y2
ID2;X2;Y2;X1;Y1
```

Output is always fixed to a pattern: ID;pair1;pair2. All values are strings, not numbers and can contain any character or number.

I tried couple of ways and here is my latest result, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations
 
def generate_combinations(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as infile, open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
         id_value = None
         x_values = []
         y_values = []
 
         for line in lines:
             line = line.strip()
 
             if line == ';':
                 if id_value is not None:
                     # Generate combinations for the previous block
                     combinations_list = []
                     for x_combination in combinations(x_values, len(y_values)):
                         for y_combination in permutations(y_values):
                             combination = [id_value] + [f"{x};{y}" for x, y in zip(x_combination, y_combination)]
                             combinations_list.append(';'.join(combination) + '\n')
 
                      # Write combinations to the output file
                      outfile.writelines(combinations_list)
  
                  # Reset values for the new block
                  id_value = None
                  x_values = []
                  y_values = []
              else:
                  if not r_value:
                      id_value = line
                  elif len(x_values) < len(y_values):
                      x_values.append(line)
                  else:
                     y_values.append(line)
 
         # Generate combinations for the last block
         combinations_list = []
         for x_combination in combinations(x_values, len(y_values)):
             for y_combination in permutations(y_values):
                 combination = [id_value] + [f"{x};{y}" for x, y in zip(x_combination, y_combination)]
                 combinations_list.append(';'.join(combination) + '\n')
 
         # Write combinations to the output file for the last block
         outfile.writelines(combinations_list)
```